# Time optimization in SMTP mails using PHPMailer

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I have developed a PHP code which extracts email addresses from a list and sends emails one after another. I am using the PHPMailer library to send through my Gmail account.

My intention is to send about 5000 emails at a time. (Don't worry, it's not spam. These are notifications about an upcoming event to its attendees.) However, until now my best output is 133 emails where the code runs for 5 minutes. It's very slow. I guess I can extend the execution time with `set_time_limit()`. Still, it would need around 3 hours to completely finish sending all the emails.

Few clarifications regarding my code:
 1. I have kept the SMTP connection alive with `SMTPKeepAlive = true;`
 2. The setup of the email, as well as the connection, is outside the loop. Inside the loop I only extract the email id, pass it to AddAddress and send.
 3. I would like to stick to my own code rather than using a mailing list website/software.

Is it possible to optimize the process and finish it within a couple of minutes?

Comment: It sounds like you're doing most things right. Did you base your code on the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer? Gmail is never going to be very fast though. For more speed, submit your messages to a local MTA that can act as a relay. Using that mechanism I can get up to around 1 million messages/hour; 5000 would take only a few seconds.

Comment: Use a profiler to find where your code spends its time.

Comment: Did you say that your leaving the SMTP connection open and sending all 5000 emails within the same SMTP session? Is there any reason for this because many firewalls (including the one where I work) drop long connections times. There a also rates on how many emails can be sent within an hour from a certain IP.

Comment: If you relay through a local server, there are no connection limits, no firewall involved. If you send from a cron script, no execution time limits apply (by default). It's also far more reliable than sending directly via a remote server.

Answer (score 0):

For this amount of email I would use a transactional mail service like SendGrid or something similar, because when you want to send an email (or one email to multiple addresses) trough the service you just need to create a request to the API. And this takes only a few milliseconds contrary to always connecting to the smtp server,~500ms.

Note: I'm not affiliated in any way with SendGrid, I just love their product (and discovered they services in a situation similar to yours). (They have a free 12,000 emails per month plan).

Note2: They also have a php [api](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php)